# How check if a String is a Valid XML with-out Displaying a Warning in PHP

Tags: xml, simplexml, php, libxml2

i was trying to check the validity of a string as xml using the  [`simplexml_load_string()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) function but it displays a lot of warning messages.

How can I check whether a string is a valid XML without using [`@` at the beginning](http://php.net/language.operators.errorcontrol) to suppress the errors and warnings?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use `libxml_use_internal_errors()` to suppress all XML errors, and `libxml_get_errors()` to iterate over them afterwards.

[Simple XML loading string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$xml = explode("\n", $xmlstr);

if ($doc !== false) {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        // Display the error how you want here
        print_r($error);
    }

    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Comment: Close to perfect...would just add that the display_xml_error function is simply a custom function to output the errors in a nice way, it can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php.
At first I thought it was an internal function that I was missing.

Comment: Be careful with `if (!$doc)`! PHP considers for example a namespaced document as empty and therefore `!$doc === TRUE`.

Comment: I ran into the problem as @David mentioned, I had to explicitly check for `if($doc !== FALSE)` instead of just `if($doc)` which would normally be enough.

Comment: I've edited the answer to incorporate the above suggestions.

Answer (score 29):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php):

> Dealing with XML errors when loading documents is a very simple task. Using the `libxml` functionality it is possible to suppress all XML errors when loading the document and then iterate over the errors.
>
> The `libXMLError` object, returned by `libxml_get_errors()`, contains several properties including the `message`, `line` and `column` (position) of the error.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0'><broken><xml></broken>");
if (!$sxe) {
    echo "Failed loading XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
```

Reference: [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

Answer (score 14):

My version like this:

```
//validate only XML. HTML will be ignored.

function isValidXml($content)
{
    $content = trim($content);
    if (empty($content)) {
        return false;
    }
    //html go to hell!
    if (stripos($content, '<!DOCTYPE html>') !== false) {
        return false;
    }

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    simplexml_load_string($content);
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();          
    libxml_clear_errors();  

    return empty($errors);
}
```

Tests:

```
//false
var_dump(isValidXml('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>'));
//true
var_dump(isValidXml('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><root></root>'));
//false
var_dump(isValidXml(null));
//false
var_dump(isValidXml(1));
//false
var_dump(isValidXml(false));
//false
var_dump(isValidXml('asdasds'));
```

Comment: note that `isValidXml('<html>Im XML!</html>')` will still return true

Answer (score 13):

try this one

```
//check if xml is valid document
public function _isValidXML($xml) {
    $doc = @simplexml_load_string($xml);
    if ($doc) {
        return true; //this is valid
    } else {
        return false; //this is not valid
    }
}
```

Comment: The question specifically asked for a solution that does not suppress the errors (using `@`).

Answer (score 3):

Here a small piece of class I wrote a while ago:

```php
/**
 * Class XmlParser
 * @author Francesco Casula <fra.casula@gmail.com>
 */
class XmlParser
{
    /**
     * @param string $xmlFilename Path to the XML file
     * @param string $version 1.0
     * @param string $encoding utf-8
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isXMLFileValid($xmlFilename, $version = '1.0', $encoding = 'utf-8')
    {
        $xmlContent = file_get_contents($xmlFilename);
        return $this->isXMLContentValid($xmlContent, $version, $encoding);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $xmlContent A well-formed XML string
     * @param string $version 1.0
     * @param string $encoding utf-8
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isXMLContentValid($xmlContent, $version = '1.0', $encoding = 'utf-8')
    {
        if (trim($xmlContent) == '') {
            return false;
        }

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $doc = new DOMDocument($version, $encoding);
        $doc->loadXML($xmlContent);

        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        libxml_clear_errors();

        return empty($errors);
    }
}
```

It works fine with streams and [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) as well for testing purposes.

Comment: added check to avoid `DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input` error

Answer (score 2):

### Case

Occasionally check availability of a Google Merchant XML feed.

The feed is without DTD, so [`validate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php) won't work.

### Solution

```
// disable forwarding those load() errors to PHP
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
// initiate the DOMDocument and attempt to load the XML file
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->load($path_to_xml_file);
// check if the file contents are what we're expecting them to be
// `item` here is for Google Merchant, replace with what you expect
$success = $dom->getElementsByTagName('item')->length > 0;
// alternatively, just check if the file was loaded successfully
$success = null !== $dom->actualEncoding;
```

[`length`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) above contains a number of how many products are actually listed in the file. You can use your tag names instead.

### Logic

You can call [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) on any other tag names (`item` I used is for Google Merchant, your case may vary), or read [other properties](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.synopsis) on the `$dom` object itself. The logic stays the same: instead of checking if there were errors when loading the file, I believe actually trying to manipulate it (or specifically check if it contains the values you actually need) would be more reliable.

Most important: unlike [`validate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php), this won't require your XML to have a DTD.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
<?php
/**
* Check XML validity.
* 
* @param string $xmlstr
* @return bool
*/
public function checkXML($xmlstr)
{
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
    if (!$doc) {
        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        if (count($errors)) {
            libxml_clear_errors();
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```